# HW Probability Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many different bridge hands are possible containing five spades, three diamonds, threee clubs, and two hearts?

Please provide some helpful hints as I am unfamiliar with most card games.

Comment: All you need to know about bridge for this is that in a standard deck there are four suits, each of thirteen cards, and a bridge hand is thirteen cards.  So select five of thirteen spades, etc.

Comment: Normal deck of card used: 4 suits, 13 cards of each suit. Bridge hands have 13 cards. So your required number of cards of each suit totals 13 the number of cards in a hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much card knowledge is needed here, only that a bridge hand is any collection of $13$ cards. These are chosen from the standard $52$-card deck, which has $13$ spades, $13$ hearts, $13$ diamonds, and $13$ clubs. The $13$ spades are all different, as are the $13$ hearts, and so on.

For counting the hands of the kind described, note that the $5$ spades can be chosen in $\binom{13}{5}$ ways. For every way of choosing the spades, there are 
$???$ ways of choosing the $3$ diamonds from the $13$ available. And for every way of choosing the spades and diamonds, there are $???$ $\dots$.

Answer (score 3):

- Since a bridge hand has 13 cards, and every deck of cards has $13$ spades, $13$ diamonds, $13$ clubs, and $13$ hearts $= 52$ cards in all, and
- since a "hand" is a "hand" (that is, the order in which the cards in
  a hand doesn't matter,

we thus have

$\displaystyle \binom{13}{5}$ ways of choosing five spades, and for each way of choosing spades, there are

$\quad\times$
$\displaystyle \binom{13}{3}$ ways of choosing 3 diamonds. Then for each $8$-card hand thus far chosen, there are

$\quad \times$

$\quad\vdots\quad$ ways of choosing 3 clubs...

$\quad\times$

$\quad \vdots \quad$ ways of choosing 2 hearts for each partial hand thus far determined.
$=======================$

And we are almost done.

Now we simply calculate the *product* of the binomial coefficients (why the product?) to determine the total number of hands bridge hands that can be formed subject to the given restrictions
: $$\binom{13}{5}\times \binom{13}{3} \times \binom{13}{3}\times \binom{13}{2}$$ 
Recall $$\binom nr = \dfrac{n!}{r!(n-r)}$$

Comment: This is one of the problems where you can check the answer at the back of the book, and the solution seems to be 8, 211, 173, and 256.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the solution to the right problem?

Comment: Yes. This is the primary source of confusion

Comment: It does; the professor had explained something in class from chapter 1 and I had to go back and do one of the beginning problems using a the bars and stars method for distinguishable and indistinguishable elements, so I was thinking that I to use this method. But I see not, thanks for the help.

Comment: You're very welcome! Yes, it can get confusing distinguishing between methods of constructing combinations. It helped me (for study purposes) to create a chart/table listing the various methods and the conditions required/circumstances appropriate for each + picking an informative example of when/how each is used/computed.

Comment: @amWhy  Two points:  shouldn't the second term in your solution be squared rather than multiplied by 2?  Secondly, if I use the square, and actually calculate the value of the answer, it's 8,211,173,256... Just like the unjustly reviled book textbook said!

Comment: Well, someone added the "and" before we got to see it...

Comment: Yes, indeed @User58220 ! Nice "detective" work!

Comment: Hi AMy. Maybe I cannot be on line cause of expiring my int line. +

Comment: JuanSancen: note that the solution in you text is correct...its *one* very large number: $8,211,173,256$ (not four separate numbers!) I hope that helps.  If you compute $\binom{13}{5}\times \binom{13}{3} \times \binom{13}{3}\times \binom{13}{2}$, you will get that answer.  I hope it helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

amWhy and Andre have great answers, but I'd like to expand on amWhy's post if your still having trouble with why you're supposed to take the product:

In combinatorics we multiply when the problem can be broken down in stages. This means, in the first stage there are $x_1$ different outcomes, in the second stage there are $x_2$ many outcomes, and continuing until the last stage (call it stage $n$), we have $x_n$ many outcomes. Then, if the outcomes are independent and the outcomes of each stage is distinct, then the problem has $x_1\cdot x_2 \cdots x_n$ many combined outcomes.